# Own implementation of "strcpy" (C) doesn’t work! Conflicting types. Why?

Tags: c, implicit-declaration

My university advised me to learn `C` as a `Java`-programmer from this document: “[C for Java Programmers](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/jebari_chaker/papers/C_for_Java_Programmers.pdf)” by J. Maassen.

On page 46 (PDF-page 47), Maassen tries to implement his own version of `C`’s `strcpy` function, called `my_strcpy`

```
char *my_strcpy(char *destination, char *source)
{
    char*p = destination;
    while (*source != '\0')
    {
        *p++ = *source++;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

I’ve tried to write a program with this function.
Take a look at page 45 (PDF-page 46). Here, Maassen has introduced his first version of a `strcpy`-method. He included `stdio.h` and copied `strA` to `strB`.

So, the following program should work, shouldn’t it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char strA[80] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes";
char strB[80];

int main(void)
{
    my_strcpy(strB, strA);
    puts(strB);
}

char *my_strcpy(char *destination, char *source)
{
    char*p = destination;
    while (*source != '\0')
    {
        *p++ = *source++;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

Well, actually it doesn’t.
Because every time I’m compiling this program, I get the following errors:

```
PROGRAM.c:12:7: error: conflicting types for ‘my_strcpy’
 char *my_strcpy(char *destination, char *source)
       ^
PROGRAM.c:8:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘my_strcpy’ was here
 mystrcpy(strB, strA);
 ^
```

Why isn’t this program working? I mean, it should work, shouldn’t it?
I’ve seen a similar implementation of a `strcpy` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14723417). And that implementation isn’t working either! I’m getting the same errors!

What’s wrong?

Comment: "previous implicit declaration" - notice the word "implicit". You don't have a proper function prototype. Google "C implicit declaration error", and you'll surely find more information.

Comment: You really shouldn't blame your tools before you know what you're doing. You seem outraged, yet you haven't even read the error message.

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in your questions. In general, it makes it difficult to copy/past your code and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Indeed, avoid blaming somebody or so eone else in a public forum, until you're very sure it is not a case of PEBKAC... I'd edit that part out, before the question attracts more downvotes. The question is otherwise fine (though there probably are duplicates), this is one of C "gotchas".

Comment: ...and instead of line numbers before every line, you can indicate the error message lines by adding comments to end of those lines, if needed.

Comment: @hyde Too bad "PEBKAC" is not 15 characters long, else I would have found my new one-word-rules-all jolly joker SO comment...

Comment: @Incognito: don't add "HEY THANK YOU SOLVED AWSUM" to the top of the question (I've rolled back that edit). If you think that an answer solved your problem, accept it - that's how things work here. Also, read the FAQ/help center soon so as to familiarize yourself with general concepts of the SO etiquette.

Comment: @H2CO3: Ok, I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the compiler sees line 8 of your program, it has no idea what types `my_strcpy` takes or returns. Either switch the order of `main` and `my_strcpy` in the source file or add a prototype of `my_strcpy` before `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Java where methods can be used before they are declared textually, C requires a prototype for each function that you call. In case you do not provide a prototype, C uses default rules, requiring prototype-less functions to take parameters matching the type of whatever you pass for the first time, and return an `int`.

To fix this, add this line ahead of `main`:

```
char *my_strcpy(char *, char *);
```

Note: the real `strcpy` allows pointers to constants to be passed as the second parameter. This lets you make calls like this:

```
my_strcpy(dest, "quick brown fox");
```

I suggest that you change the declaration and the definition as follows:

```
char *my_strcpy(char *, const char *);

char *my_strcpy(char *destination, const char *source)
{
      char* p = destination;
      while (*source != '\0')
      {
          *p++ = *source++;
      }
      *p = '\0';
     return destination;
}
```

Another thing to note is that you could do with `destination` the same thing that you did with the `source`, avoiding `p`. You can also use the implied comparison to zero - another thing not available in Java:

```
char *my_strcpy(char *destination, const char *source)
{
      while (*source) // Removed comparison to zero
      {
          *destination++ = *source++;
      }
      *destination = '\0';
     return destination;
}
```

Finally, to avoid the assignment of zero at the end of your loop, you could go for a body-less one-liner implementation:

```
char *my_strcpy(char *destination, const char *source)
{
      while (*destination++ = *source++)
          ;
     return destination;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `my_strcpy` the first time, the compiler hasn't seen it yet and has no *prototype* for it. So it (possibly) defines it automatically as a function returning `int`.

You need to either supply a prototype before the call:

```
char *my_strcpy(char *destination, char *source);

int main(void)
{
    my_strcpy(strB, strA);
    puts(strB);
}

char *my_strcpy(char *destination, char *source)
{
    ...
```

or define the call before actually calling it (i.e. placing main() at bottom).

For large projects you would place all of your prototypes in an external file that you would then include:

```
#include "my_functions.h"
```

BTW, `main` usually is passed arguments from the command line, so you would define it as

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    return 0;
}
```

returning a valid return code (e.g. 0 if all went well). You may use *pragma*s to tell the compiler that some arguments aren't really needed in the called code.