# Where are strcpy and other C library functions defined (as opposed to declared)?

Tags: c++, c

I found the declaration of function `strcpy` in string.h

```
/* Copy SRC to DEST.  */
extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, __const char *__restrict __src)
 __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
```

but where can I find the definition and body for this function?

Comment: You are linking with std library by default. Definition is in there.

Comment: nonnull is not the function body. [See this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bnonnull_007d-function-attribute-2905).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.h` files contains the declaration of the functions. It means it is the contract telling how to call the function but in the "world" of the C compiler. The function itself (i.e. the code) is defined elsewhere. It might be in another `.c` file but that is not necessarly the case. It is possible to link other object files or even libraries written in other languages.
`strcpy()` is typically present in the stdlib and is very often written in assembly.

```
extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, __const char *__restrict __src)
__THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
```

This function declares several things that are interesting for your application:
`extern` this keyword tells that the **definition** of this function is another compilation unit, i.e. it's not defined in the `.c` file that included that header.

the function takes 2 parameters that are pointer to characters and return a pointer to character.
The 2 passed pointer have following properties:

the first one called `__dest` (the name could be omitted but giving it a name gives a hint at what it is) points to a memory area of unknown size that **may be modified** by the function. We can deduce that because there is no `__const` modifier.

the second one called `__src` points to a character string of unknown length which the function promises to not modify `__const` qualifier.

Furthermore the function assumes that both pointer do not point on overlapping areas, that is expressed by the  `__restrict` qualifiers. Passing pointer that overlap will yield `undefined behaviour`.

example: `strcpy(buff, buff+1);` often used to delete a character from a string is `undefined` and can fail.

The `__THROW` is something compiler specific and is imo something for the C++ compiler, as C has no concept of throwing (exceptions).

The `__nonnull ((1,2))` is also compiler specific but I suppose it is the `__attribute__((nonnull ((1,2))))` of gcc, which in this case instructs the compiler that the function never takes `NULL` pointer and allows it to warn if the programmers erroneously trie to call it with such.

Answer (score 4):

It's the declaration, not the definition. "How this works" resides in the library implementation.

The implementation of, for example, GNU C Library can be [found online](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html).

For this particular function, [an SO question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723381/how-strcpy-works-behind-the-scenes), too.

Answer (score 0):

The library functions will have defination in `.c` files that correspond to the `.h` files.
Its about how libraries are created in c. the procedure is,
first to put the declaration of functions in a `.h` file then
Put the definition of the functions in a `.c` file.
Read about how library is created in C and C++.

Comment: a) Header-only libraries. b) C++ c) `code` is not supposed to be used to highlight search terms.