# character pointer function to copy a string in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void pal_string_copy(char * source, char * destination){

for(int i = 0; i < *source.length(); i++)
{
    if(isalpha(*source[i]))
    {

        destination += toupper(*source[i]) ;

    }


}
```

We have to use this function with those parameters to make a copy of a string while stripping out the spaces and only taking letters and then making them uppcase to check if it's a palindrome(done in a different function. I get the error

> Member reference base type 'char *' is not a structure or union

When calling the function, is it possible to pass in strings as parameters since a string is a vector of characters?

Comment: _"a string is a vector of characters"_ No it isn't

Comment: `*source.length()` what trickery is this?

Comment: Where has this `.length()` come from? `char` doesn't have member functions, and neither does `char*` (which is what you really intended to use, but for some reason keep dereferencing `source` instead?)

Comment: `char` has no member `length()`, did you mean `std::string`?

Comment: `*source[i]` isn't right either.

Comment: `destination += toupper(*source[i]) ;` is absolutely not going to do what you think it does

Comment: Take a look at [How strcpy works behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14723381/10077)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a non-existant `length()` method on a `char` value. That is what the error message is complaining about, because `char` is not a type that has methods.  You are thinking of the `std::string` class instead (which you *should* be using instead of `char*`). To get the length of a `char*` string, use the `strlen()` function.

Also, you are dereferencing the pointers incorrectly.  Don't use both `*` and `[]` operators together. In your example, `[]` will suffice to access individual characters from the `source` pointer. But you are also using the `+=` operator with a `char*` pointer, which is wrong, too. Again, you are thinking of the `std::string` class.

If you are going to use `char*` pointers, you need to use something more like this instead:

```
// prerequisite: the destination must point to a char[] buffer
// that is allocated to at least the same length as the
// char[] buffer that the source is pointing at...
void pal_string_copy(char * source, char * destination) {
    int len = strlen(source);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (isalpha(source[i])) {
            *destination++ = (char) toupper(source[i]);
        }
    }
    *destination = '\0';    
}
```

Otherwise, use `std::string` instead, eg:

```
void pal_string_copy(const std::string & source, std::string & destination) {
    destination.clear();
    size_t len = source.length();
    destination.reserve(len);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (isalpha(source[i])) {
            destination += (char) toupper(source[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
std::string pal_string_copy(const std::string & source) {
    std::string destination;
    size_t len = source.length();
    destination.reserve(len);
    for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (isalpha(source[i])) {
            destination += (char) toupper(source[i]);
        }
    }
    return destination; 
}
```

Or, using STL algorithms:

```
std::string pal_string_copy(const std::string & source) {
    std::string destination;
    destination.reserve(source.length());
    std::copy_if(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(destination), [](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c); });
    std::transform(destination.begin(), destination.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::toupper(c); });    
    return destination; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mixed two concepts - C strings as `char *` and C++ string as `std::string` and you try to use `char *` like they are `std::string` (length() method += etc), so your code in C++ should be something like this:

```
std::string pal_string_copy( const std::string &str )
{
    std::string destination;
    for(char c : str ) {
        if(isalpha(c))
            destination += toupper(c);
    }
    return destination;
}
```

or if you have to work with C style strings then you cannot use methods, but C functions `strlen()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`char` has no member called `length`. Instead of `char*` you should use `string` data type.  and `destination` string take as of `reference` type so that modification will affect in calling function, otherwise it will just a pass by value .

```
void pal_string_copy(std::string source, std::string &destination){

        for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
                if(isalpha(source[i])) {
                        destination += toupper(source[i]) ;
                }
        }
}
int main() {
        std :: string a = "hello", b ;
        pal_string_copy(a,b);
        std::cout <<" b = " <<b<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How you can copy to `b` without changing `b`?

Comment: Nothing gets copied into `b`, only  into a *copy* of the original, empy `b`.

Comment: "isn't it or may be I am wrong ?" @FredLarson tried to tell you - how can you copy to `destination` if you pass it by value.

Comment: I got it. I changed my answer @Slava . Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: I got your point @FredLarson I should have read it clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to treat a `char *` as a `std::string` type object. To use a `char *`, you should look up functions inherited from C to handle strings (e.g., `std::strlen` to get the length of the string).

Additionally, how you operate on the pointer is incorrect. A better way of writing this is trying to use iterators and the STL to minimize such errors:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
   std::string orig = "test123", dest;

   std::cout << "Original: " << orig << std::endl;

   //Copies the string orig into dest but by only keeping the letters
   std::copy_if(orig.begin(),orig.end(),std::back_inserter(dest),[](char ch) { return std::isalpha(ch); });
   //Transforms each character in dest to upper case
   std::for_each(dest.begin(),dest.end(),[](char &ch) { ch = std::toupper(ch); });

   std::cout << "Transformed: " << dest << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT

Here is a version that iterates through the string but avoiding the use of pointers:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
   std::string orig = "test123", dest;

   std::cout << "Original: " << orig << std::endl;

   for( auto ch : orig ) {
       if(std::isalpha(ch)) dest += std::toupper(ch);
   }

   std::cout << "Transformed: " << dest << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Though it is good to use standard algorithms, but not by price of twice iteration IMHO.

Comment: @Slava I agree with you in principle, but my goal was to get the OP aware what the standard algorithms could do to avoid programming mistakes. Plus, this should be fine for most cases, and you can optimize more effectively once you have an error-free version of your code. In any case, I added a second version that only loops once for comparison.